# creating a full width dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm tying to make a full width drop-down menu (which I've never done before) with this structure http://jsfiddle.net/cstEv/

with the css I have currently I can't center the subnav `ul` because the `ul` poistioning origin is that of the parent `li`.
Does anybody know how to get the `ul` `.children` to center under the `#menu` div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made the following changes:

From:

```
.children {
            display: none;
            width: 560px;
            min-height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            left: -244px;
            top: 48px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #c7c7c7;
        }
.children  li {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
```

To:

```
.children{
            display: none;
            min-height: 30px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
            top: 10px;
        }
        li:nth-child(3) .children{
            right: 252px;
        }
        li:last-child .children{
            right: 502px;
        }
        li:nth-child(3) .children  li {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 628px !important;
        }

        li:last-child .children li{
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 628px !important;
        }
```

Look at the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkpy5/3/)

Comment: that's great but what i need is for the  `children` `ul` to be full width (the same size as the menu ) and not the size of the parent `li`

Comment: If the structure has to change to achieve this that's cool also

Comment: yeah, but the last submenu is off center

Comment: [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/hkpy5/3/) P.S.: I'm editing the original answer with the new modifications and updated fiddle ;)